# How to sequentially add seaborn boxplots to the same axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Is there a way how to add multiple seaborn boxplots to one figure **sequentially**?

Taking example from [Time-series boxplot in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507404/time-series-boxplot-in-pandas):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 480
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(n), index=pd.date_range(start="2014-02-01", periods=n, freq="H"))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
seaborn.boxplot(ts.index.dayofyear, ts, ax=ax)
```

This gives me one series of box-plots?

[image]

Now, is there any way to plot two time-series like this one the same plot side-by-side? I want to plot it in the function that would have `make_new_plot` boolean parameter for separating the boxplots that are plotted from the for-loop.

If I try to just call it on the same axis, it gives me the overlapping plots:

[image]

I know that it is possible to concatenate the dataframes and make box plots of the concatenated dataframe together, but I would not want to have this plotting function returning any dataframes.

Is there some other way to make it? Maybe it is possible to somehow manipulate the width&position of boxes to achieve this? The fact tact that I need a time-series of boxplots & matplotlib "positions" parameter is on purpose not supported by seaborn makes it a bit tricky for me to figure out how to do it.

**Note** that it is NOT the same as eg. [Plotting multiple boxplots in seaborn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552489/plotting-multiple-boxplots-in-seaborn), because I want to plot it sequentially without returning any dataframes from the plotting function.

Comment: where should the second set of boxes be? Each new box alongside the other (like hue-nesting), or as a whole group on the right, at positions 52...71?

Comment: @DizietAsahi boxes alongside each other for each time-step. I sorta managed to do a workaround in pure matplotlib but still wondering if there is a smarted way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following if you want to have hue nesting of different time-series in your boxplots.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 480
ts0 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(n), index=pd.date_range(start="2014-02-01", periods=n, freq="H"))
ts1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(n), index=pd.date_range(start="2014-02-01", periods=n, freq="H"))
ts2 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(n), index=pd.date_range(start="2014-02-01", periods=n, freq="H"))

def ts_boxplot(ax, list_of_ts):
    new_list_of_ts = []
    for i, ts in enumerate(list_of_ts):
        ts = ts.to_frame(name='ts_variable')
        ts['ts_number'] = i
        ts['doy']=ts.index.dayofyear
        new_list_of_ts.append(ts)
    plot_data = pd.concat(new_list_of_ts)
    sns.boxplot(data=plot_data, x='doy', y='ts_variable', hue='ts_number', ax=ax)
    return ax

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
ax = ts_boxplot(ax, [ts0, ts1, ts2])
```